# Do Wii U Gamepads come with a matching Stylus or are they all gray?

Tags: controllers, wii-u

I just got a used Wii U from a friend. It's a Black console, but the Stylus that came with the Gamepad is gray.

Do Gamepads come with a matching Stylus or are they all gray?

I don't see any replacement Styluses on Nintendo's website for Black or White consoles, only Gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Wii U consoles have their corresponding color of Stylus.
The White Wii U comes with a White Stylus while the black Wii U comes with a kind of Matte Black Stylus. Even the Zelda one have this Matte Black Stylus.

 
 Source: https://www.nintendo.es/Wii-U/La-consola/Packs-de-la-consola/Premium-Pack/Premium-Pack-664662.html
(This site is in Spanish but you can switch between Premium Package and Basic Package, below the image of Wii U comes the complete package content)

Comment: Weird, looks like the Black Wii U has a Gray Stylus (if you open the page and zoom in, is Gray) and the White Wii U has a White Stylus.

Comment: How Gray is your stylus, like White Gray, or it's similar to the one on the Nintendo page?

Comment: [Is like Gray 50% (exact middle of Black and White)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8wh.jpg). [It has a Nintendo logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Hzp.jpg) and my friend says that it came with the console, and it looks the same as the Nintendo page.

Comment: I have a black wiiu and mine also came with a grey stylus.